Resetting form on duplicate value
I have an Access database for where the user is entering unique IDs.  The database checks before update that the ID does not exist already.  The database currently warns the user that it has been used before but I want to force it to clear the data and force them reenter a correct value after the warning.  I can not seem to get anything to work.
Private Sub KitID2_BeforeUpdate()

    Dim varMasterCartonSKU As Variant
    Dim strCriteria As String

    strCriteria = "[KitID]='" & Forms!MainForm!KitID2.Value & "'"
    Debug.Print strCriteria
    varMasterCartonSKU = DLookup("KitID", "Used_KitID_Tbl", strCriteria)
    If Not IsNull(varMasterCartonSKU) Then
        If MsgBox("This KitID has been used Before!", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            
        End If
    Else

    End If
    
End Sub


How did you go about building that event procedure?  I thought Access would expect Private Sub KitID2_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)  Then within the procedure, when you want to abort the pending update, you can do Cancel = True

Get rid of the If statement around the prompt, since it sounds like there is no option to submit a duplicate ID. Then clear the Value of the Control.  Access may require you set focus to the control prior to clearing.
MsgBox("This KitID has been used Before!  Please enter a KitId that hasn't been used.", vbOKOnly)
Forms!MainForm!KitID2.Value = ""        

